# Selecting Matrix element using vector elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a way in Matlab to select a matrix element based off the elements in a vector? I don't think my description is clear, but what I effectively want to do is something similar to:

```
A=zeros(3,3,3) %3d matrix
A(1,1,2)=5
b=[1,1,2]
A(b)=5
```

Meaning, some easy way to select one element from a matrix using the entries in a vector as arguments. This exact example does not work because the last line counts b as a single argument, not three. I could write A(b(1),b(2),b(3)) but what I'm really looking for here is if there's a nice way of doing.

Comment: I thought to use [`sub2ind()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), but `sub2ind(size(A),b)` apparently treats each element in `b` separately...

Comment: @Adriaan because its `sub2ind(size(A),b(:,1),b(:,2),b(:,3))`

Comment: You can use a cell array instead of a vector: `b={1,1,2}; A(b{:}) = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Use [sub2ind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to find the linear index**

You can define a function called `findLinearIndex` such that it convert the vector elements to the linear index of `A`:

```
findLinearIndex = @(A,b) sub2ind(size(A), b(1), b(2), b(3))
A(findLinearIndex(A,b)) = 5
```

**Method 2: Convert the vector to cell array by [num2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html?searchHighlight=num2cell&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)**

Then, you can use `{:}` to get the index

```
b_cell = num2cell(b) ;
A(b_cell{:}) = 5
```